# Is there a way for chatbot that use chatterbot module in python consider sentences like "what is your name" and "what your name" as the same sentence?

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

Sorry if my english feel clunky, it not my first language

I'm using Python 3.11.3

I coded a conversation chatbot using the chatterbot module. So far it work great, but a big problem is that it consider sentences like "what is your name"/"what your name" or "what are you doing"/"what're you doing" as two diffence sentences, which i have to make response for those question too, or else the chatbot gonna otherwise doesn't understand the question

Are there any way i can make the chatbot consider sentences like that as the same?
My code:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
from chatterbot.response_selection import get_random_response

my_bot = ChatBot(name='Bot', read_only=True,
                     response_selection_method=get_random_response,
                     logic_adapters=[
                         {
                             'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.SpecificResponseAdapter',
                             'input_text': 'empty',
                             'output_text': ''
                         },
                         {
                             'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
                             'default_response': 'i honestly have no idea how to respond to that',
                             'maximum_similarity_threshold': 0.7
                         },
                         {
                             'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation'
                         }

                     ], preprocessors=[
                             'chatterbot.preprocessors.clean_whitespace',

                             'chatterbot.preprocessors.unescape_html',

                             'chatterbot.preprocessors.convert_to_ascii'
                     ]
                     )
    while True:
        user_input = input('Me: ')
        if user_input.lower() == 'quit':
            break
        else:
            bot_response = my_bot.get_response(user_input)
            print(bot_response)
```

I haven't really try anything beside looking online for solution (i'm new at coding)